# overlay animation should not be shown outside the underlying div

Tags: html, css, animation

here is my attempt to have overlay animation effect but overlay is not hiding after getting out of the underlying div- 'overflowTest'

```css
#overflowTest {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 5px black;
}

#box{
position: absolute;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border: 5px solid black;
animation-name: go;
animation-duration: 6s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes go {
0%{
border: 3px solid red;
}
100%{
border: 3px solid red;
transform: translateX(200px);
}

}
```

```html
<div id="overflowTest"><div id="box"></div><div id="hel">This is demo text to test overlay animation on it</div></div>
```

please help in **hiding the overlay** when it is outside the 'overflowTest' div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to the parent `#overflowTest`.

An Element with `position: absolute;` will behave absolute to the first parent with a relative position. If no other is declared as relative, it will behave absolute to the page itself, which was happening before.

```css
#overflowTest {
  position: relative;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 5px black;
}

#box{
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  animation-name: go;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes go {
  0%{
    border: 3px solid #ffaaaa;
  }
  100%{
    border: 3px solid #ffaaaa;
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="overflowTest">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="hel">This is demo text to test overlay animation on it</div>
</div>
```

Hope that is what you are looking for!

Comment: I want the overlay to be shown but not outside the box

Comment: I have updated my Snippet. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The property you should use is `z-index`.
Setting `z-index:-1`; will help you get the desired result. `z-index` works only when position property is also added.
Try this,

```css
#overflowTest {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 5px black;
  
}

#box{
position: absolute;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border: 5px solid black;
animation-name: go;
animation-duration: 6s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
transform: rotate(45deg);
z-index:-1;
}

@keyframes go {
0%{
border: 3px solid red;
}
100%{
border: 3px solid red;
transform: translateX(200px);
}

}
```

```html
<div id="overflowTest"><div id="box"></div><div id="hel">This is demo text to test overlay animation on it</div></div>
```

Hope it helps.!! **Happy Coding!!**

Comment: not what i want

Comment: Can you specify exactly what your need is?